# What are the guidelines for community wiki on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, meta, community-wiki

When should questions on Meta Stack Overflow be community wiki? I have seen a lot of non-community-wiki questions here that would have been community wiki on Stack Overflow. Obviously the rules are going to be different here, but what are those rules?

Comment: By the way, if this should be CW, just tell me. :)

Answer (score 4):

When you want to have a question that has a collection of information from the entire community. For example a community edited list of some sorts. (just like CW's were supposed to be)

Community Wikis have been misunderstood for a long time now. Here's a post that's a prime example of what a CW post should be.

- [How Does Stackoverflow Work? (The Official FAQ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq)

So any post that could possibly contain information that the community decides on and edits. Think of it as a wiki article (sorta)

Answer (score 4):

I would certainly hope that the CW works here as Olafur intended, but all too often I am already seeing instances of people who will make a topic CW simply to shield themselves from down votes (you know who you are). I hope this behavior doesn't continue.

Comment: The hell you say! People posting imflammatory question on metaSO and using CW to shield themselves? That cannot be! *cough* *cough* http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/245/ *cough* *cough*